# Weighting a set of numbers based on the numbers' relative proximity to n

Tags: r, distance, weighted

I'm trying to figure out how to scale a set of numbers based on their relative proximity to a given number. Let's say I have [1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10] for example, and n is 8. 7 and 9 would have a lot of weight, and 10's weight would be comparable, though lesser. 1's weight on the other hand would be relatively infinitesimal. How can I go about accomplishing this?

I came up with this (R):

```
test.2 <- function(vec, n) {
    weight_vec <- 1 / abs(n-vec)
    scaled <- vec * weight_vec
    return(scaled)
}
```

which seems to work insofar as it scales the numbers based on their proximity, but the problem occurs, in this instance, in the difference for the results for 7 and 9 (and also 6 and 10):

```
test.2(c(1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10), 8)
[1] 0.1428571 0.6000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 3.0000000 7.0000000 9.0000000 5.0000000
```

they should ideally output the same value. I should state that I do not have the mathematical know-how to claim to know what I am doing.

Comment: What about `abs(1/(8 - x))`?

Comment: @jay.sf that does work! two questions: does this function have a name, and is there a generally accepted way of doing what I am trying to do?

(also, what if the set has 8 as an item? trying to divide 1 by 0, R gives the output Inf, which is not optimal)

Comment: You don't have any problem in your function, but it depends on if you want to have weight only or weighted vector.

Comment: you could consider using the laplacian kernel. `exp(-abs(n - vec))` in this case, if `n` is in `vec` it will still work

Comment: @jay.sf what is the difference between what you wrote ie `abs(1/(8-x))` versus what OP has ie `1/(abs(n-vec))`?

Comment: It is often improper to do arithmetic operations on ordinal numbers because the intended weights may be conditioned on the range of ordinal values.  So say 100 was added to your vector, [100, 104, 104, 106, 107, 109, 110]  The arithmetic operations may yield the same weights because the unit differences are the same.  But are the intended weights then same given the affine transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. One of which involves use of kernels. Note that the maximum weight should occur at 8 and equidistant points from 8 should have the same weights eg 7 and 9, 6 and 10 etc. Also note that the weights can be normalized by using `prop.table` function. ie `weights/sum(weights)`. The codes below provides unnormalized weights

```
## squared exponential kernel(gaussian/gibbs kernel)
vec <- 1:15
dnorm(x, 8) # you can play with sigma
```

---

```
## matern kernel
geoR::matern(abs(vec - 8), 1, 1) # You can play with phi, kappa
```

---

```
## power-exponential
exp(-abs(vec - 8)^1) # You can play with the power ie i used 1
```